# 404 error after magento 2 sitemap generation

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

I have magento 2 store and when i create a **sitemap** it works ok , but after that when i want to access the newly created sitemap it throw **404 error** page.i'm using nginx server.

**how can i fix this** ??

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Put your sitemap in the `/pub/` folder:

[image]

Then go to http://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 2):

you should check the rules of nginx, 
the root dir of nginx is set to /pub/ but that is not the correct directory for nginx to search for the sitemaps. so you should configure a location for nginx one level under the pub (the real root dir of mage2) and there will nginx find the sitemaps.
I create all sitemaps in a subdir "sitemaps". 
mine looks like this:

```
#sitemap.xml
location /sitemaps/ {
        root /var/www/production/current;
        try_files $uri =404;
        allow all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pub folder the name suggests as publicly accessible folder, so moving the file sitemap.xml from HTML to the pub folder will resolve the issue